# VPS[DebianSQ] - Super user can't mount

Tags: debian

Having trouble with mySQL /tmp directory being to small. Need to resize the size from 16MB to something bigger.

Only problem is that it won't allow me to resize it.

```
root@robocop:/mnt# umount /tmp
umount: /tmp: must be superuser to umount

Trying to determine if something is using it.
root@robocop:/#  lsof |grep /tmp
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() usbfs file system /proc/bus/usb
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() xfs file system /var/lib/vservers/lv49
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() proc file system /var/lib/vservers/lv49/robocop/proc
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tmpfs file system /var/lib/vservers/lv49/robocop/tmp
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() devpts file system /var/lib/vservers/lv49/robocop/de                                                                v/pts

root@robocop:/mnt# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/hdv1              10G  6.8G  3.3G  68% /
none                   16M     0   16M   0% /tmp
```

Im pretty sure there should be more space in the /tmp. Why can't I umount it.

Further more do you guys have any recommendation on /tmp handling.

BTW: Had an account here a while ago. Can't remember my password and mail server has closed down due to the economy.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your VPS provider is using Linux-VServer. The /tmp filesystem is not under your control within the VPS. Your VPS provider will have to [increase it](http://linux-vserver.org/Frequently_Asked_Questions#I_want_to_.28re.29mount_a_partition_in_a_running_guest_..._but_the_guest_has_no_rights_.28capability.29_to_.28re.29mount.3F) from the default of 16MB for you. If they won't do this, you can [configure MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-files.html) to use a different directory for temporary files.

Comment: Thanks they fixed it by combining the /tmp with the /dev/hdv1 filesystem